# Grails - global plugin registration

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, application-state

I am developing a series of grails plugins that need to register themselves with the application when it starts.  This would allow me to create a factory to lookup plugin class instances by a friendly string name at runtime.

What would be the best approach for storage of this data globally within the grails application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [**GrailsPluginManager**](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/GrailsPluginManager.html) which eventually does that for you. Something like below in `BootStrap` will be feasible:

```
grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('pluginManager').allPlugins.each{ plugin->
    println "Plugin Info ${plugin.name} - ${plugin.version}"
}
```

or just

```
pluginManager.getGrailsPluginForClassName("FooPlugin")
```

if you already have the bean accessible.